# Fantasy novel that starts from the perspective of an insect race

Tags: story-identification, novel

The book starts off from the perspective of an insect race (possibly from the queen's perspective) and covers their discovery of humans. They don't understand how the the humans are able to use weapons such as spears and bows. Using things other than your limbs as weapons is unheard of.

The book is probably from the 00's or the 90's.

The setting was ancient or medieval I think. I don't remember the nature of the insects. They appeared, expanded as a colony and finally met and fought humans. I think that during some point in the story an insect has learned to use weapons and is using four of its limbs to shoot with two bows at the same time.

Gods might have played a part in the story.

Comment: Is the book set on Earth? In the past, present, or future? Are the insects normal Earth insects or are they mutated insects or insectoid aliens?

Comment: The setting was ancient or medieval I think. I don't remember the nature of the insects. They appeared, expanded as a colony and finally met and fought humans. I think that during some point in the story an insect has learned to use weapons and is using for of its limbs to shoot with two bows at the same time.

Comment: Sounds somewhat related to Sandkings, but it’s not

Comment: Are the insects tiny or roughly human sized?

Comment: Human sized, most likely

Comment: CJ Cherryh's _[Serpent's Reach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpent%27s_Reach)_ is more of an SF planet story, but it's in the right time period.

Comment: On the cover of my copy, the insect-alien looks more like a giant grasshopper.

Comment: Two bows! DING!!!! :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [The Younger Gods](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/18880), book four of David Edding's [Dreamers series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dreamers_(novel_series)).

The insects are a hive species and the queen is called *Mother* in the book. It opens with *Mother* musing about humans:

> And so it was that Mother began to alter the children which would go forth from the nest to search for things-to-eat in the lands beyond the high hills. And many were her alterations, for the man-things that dwelt in the lands beyond the high hills were very clever and they used weapons that were not parts of their bodies.
>
> And this gave Mother great concern, for it is most unnatural for any creature to take up things that are not parts of their bodies to use as weapons. Then it came to Mother that if the man-things could do this, could not her children do so as well? She sent forth more of the seekers of knowledge to find  creatures who had unusual parts of their bodies that gave them advantages in the search for things-to-eat.

The bit with the insect using two bows is in chapter two of the part *The Last Generation*:

> "They want—and need—to see everything, Rabbit." Then Keselo gasped. "What is that thing?" he exclaimed.
>
> Rabbit stared at the creature Keselo had just pointed out. "She actually tried to imitate Longbow!" he exclaimed.
>
> "It looks that way to me too," Keselo agreed, "but it has six limbs instead of only four, and it's carrying two bows instead of only one."
>
> "Now this I want to see," Rabbit declared. "If that thing shoots two arrows at the same time, it can kill more of its enemies than any other bug thing could ever manage."
>
> Keselo and Rabbit watched closely, and sure enough, the archer bug was killing two lion-bugs—or beetle-bugs—at the same time. The dead bugs with arrows in them began to pile up.

Comment: Thank you! This has been torturing me for the last week! The book cover made it click as soon as I saw it!

Comment: John, can you read and understand what's going on in this book without having read the 3 earlier books in the series?

Comment: @Nzall no, it won't make a lot of sense without reading the first three books. And sadly the Dreamers series is not up to Eddings' usual standard. I loved his Belgariad and Malloreon series but the Dreamers series is very disappointing, It is strictly for the die hard Eddings fans.